# is there a difference between (!object) and (object == nil)?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ObjectiveC: if (obj) {…} AND if (obj != nil) {…}, which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821282/objectivec-if-obj-and-if-obj-nil-which-is-better)

Is there a difference between these two conditions:

```
if (!object) {
 // do something
}
```

and . . .

```
if (object == nil) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no difference.  Both of those examples are exactly the same.  From the C spec **6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**:

> The result of the logical negation operator **`!`** is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type **`int`**. The expression **`!E`** is equivalent to **`(0==E)`**.

Since `nil` is 0, that last sentence applies exactly.

Comment: On iOS, nil is defined as ((void *)0) - so this may be invalid if `object` wasn't a pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3, yes, I was assuming `object` is a pointer.  If it's not, comparing against `nil` is wrong anyway.

Comment: of course, that's a valid assumption. :) Just a minor point.

Answer (score 1):

If object is of type `id` or any valid Objective-C object, then only one difference is present: readability. (i. e. from the compiler's point of view, they're both the same.)

However, there may be examples when comparing to `nil` wouldn't be very nice. For example, if for some evil illogocal reason, object was an `int`, only the two following statements would be valid:

```
if (object == 0)
```

and

```
if (!object)
```

and they would again be equivalent, but comparing an int to a pointer (which `nil` is) - except if the integer is an explicit constant 0 - is illegal and most likely result in a compiler warning (in most cases, it would still work, however...)