# When is if (!someObject) (short for someObject != nil) NOT safe?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a difference between (!object) and (object == nil)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926047/is-there-a-difference-between-object-and-object-nil)

In iOS (Objective C) development, I've frequently seen (and used) the following short hand:

```
if (someObject)
{
    // do something
}
```

To check that someObject is not nil.

In other words, to mean the same as the following:

```
if (someObject != nil)
{
    // do something
}
```

Are these two if statements actually the same or is this not safe?

Comment: This question must be a duplicate, right?

Comment: Maybe... it's kinda hard to search for this type of question though... if you find a duplicate, please do link and I'll close... thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it has been asked before... sorry, didn't find it until now! ;-P

Comment: That's funny, @Carl Norum, you answered this in said previous question! Great answer by the way!

Comment: I guess that explains why I thought I'd seen it before... =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two are exactly the same. They both are equally safe.

This feature is inherited from C, where comparing to zero is implicit.