# Is Checking The Pointer Of An Object With Negation Operator The Same As With Comparing It To Nil?

Tags: objective-c

I maybe naming it wrong, so please correct me.

I just want to know if this

```
if(!obj)
{
    //do something
}
```

is exactly the same as this

```
if(obj == nil)
{

}
```

I mean are they both checking whether the object points to nil?

Comment: @Larme thanks for the link.

Comment: I'll just add this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821282/objectivec-if-obj-and-if-obj-nil-which-is-better where the top answerer seems to have done some research on the compilation code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly the same. `!` operator turns anything other than `nil` into zero, while `nil` becomes `1`. Therefore, you get exactly the same results as the comparison with `nil`.

Similarly, using `if (obj)` is logically identical to `if (obj != nil)`. This convention is inherited from C, where pointers are commonly used in conditions, and `NULL`-checked with `!` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same. That's right. Yep.

Comment: Sorry, my answer had to be at least 30 characters long! >_<